# Removing outliers from an array

Tags: android, arraylist, gps, location, distance

This is the data I have:

```
[347.9377383405443, 333.34675887548696, 32.58649314105846, 24.62622216317879, 23.963851339673706, 22.23128479365108, 18.58339312431561, 17.481575834173356, 12.878260934629896, 12.659358796327579, 9.173382918952944, 8.225242068304267, 6.649060121150481, 5.739199037771141, 5.464135530167054, 2.702620607115836, 1.6153358770723845, 1.591554089215848, 1.004944087023187, 0.664747108333436, 0.5306254111230282, 0.5282952033744951, 0.45217868098426106, 0.3125283548781286, 0.2233209059789322]
```

Basically this are speeds, taken from the Location Service, and then sorted decreasing.

This is my code:

```
  if (filterLocation(location)) {
        int size = locations.size();
        if(size > 1){
            Double distance = distanceBetween2Locations(locations.get(size-1) , locations.get(size-2));
            Long time = (locations.get(size-1).getTime() - locations.get(size-2).getTime()) / 1000;
            Utils.appendLog(context, "speedTest LAST Speed is: " + distance/time, "D", Constants.LOCATIONS);
            speeds.add(distance/time);
        }
        if(speeds.size() > 0){
            Collections.sort(speeds);
            Collections.reverse(speeds);
            Utils.appendLog(context, "speedTest ARRAY contains " + speeds.toString(), "D", Constants.LOCATIONS);
        }
        DesiredAccuracy = 200;
        Utils.appendLog(context, "processNewLocation is Filtered.", "I", Constants.TRACKER);
    }
```

So my problem is that on some phones, The GPS gets thrown into bogus locations. sometimes 2-3 km away. where it stays for a couple of seconds, and then returns back. So I want to ignore those locations, and not track the trip if that happens. But I do want, in the case that just 1 jump exists, to track that. cause maybe the user went through a tunnel.
What I am curious to know is this: How can I know from the arraylist, where is the first object where the gap is huge.
For this case, because I have 2 locations with 340+ and then one with 32. I would want the algorithm to return me 3 (the index of the first location that is valid). But my problem is that I cannot know what the difference between them is. So I need to figure out a way to know that the biggest gap in speed is between those 2. Any ideea how to implement this?

Comment: Down voted because the question title isn't related to what you're asking.

Comment: Suggest an edit? I don't see why the title is not related to what I am asking, That is exactly what I am asking. I need to know the first item, where the gap is the biggest inside an array...

Comment: "Removing outliers from an array"

Comment: Edited, can I also get the downvote removed then? thanks